# What the difference between usual and discrete seekbars in android (xml)

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

In android studio editor I can drag and drop a seekbar or a discrete seekbar. The only difference I see in xml is style tag (style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"), if I remove it the seekbar remains discrete (it acts like discrete). So I can't figure out how does it know which seekbar is placed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"` is just a theme to show the tickbar in SeekBar just like the [doc](https://material.io/guidelines/components/sliders.html#sliders-discrete-slider) states.

> The discrete slider thumb snaps to evenly spaced tick marks along the
>   slider rail.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why the slider thumb snaps to fixed positions even if I remove this style

Comment: Did you set `setmax` to any value? If so, then it would still slides to fix position but with default outlook.